# Accessing entity attributes in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have 2  objects **Employee** and **EmployeeAddress**.

Here are my 2 objects -

**Employee**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="Employee")
    //@NamedQuery(name="Employee.findAll", query="SELECT e FROM Employee e")
    public class Employee implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private Timestamp created;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dob;

    private String email;

    @Column(name="FATHER_NAME")
    private String fatherName;

    private String firstname;

    private String lastname;

    private String married;

    @Column(name="MOTHER_NAME")
    private String motherName;

    private String telephone;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to EmployeeAddress
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="employee")
    private List<EmployeeAddress> employeeAddresses;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Timestamp getCreated() {
        return this.created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Timestamp created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public Date getDob() {
        return this.dob;
    }

    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFatherName() {
        return this.fatherName;
    }

    public void setFatherName(String fatherName) {
        this.fatherName = fatherName;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return this.firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return this.lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getMarried() {
        return this.married;
    }

    public void setMarried(String married) {
        this.married = married;
    }

    public String getMotherName() {
        return this.motherName;
    }

    public void setMotherName(String motherName) {
        this.motherName = motherName;
    }

    public String getTelephone() {
        return this.telephone;
    }

    public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }

    public List<EmployeeAddress> getEmployeeAddresses() {
        return this.employeeAddresses;
    }

    public void setEmployeeAddresses(List<EmployeeAddress> employeeAddresses) {
        this.employeeAddresses = employeeAddresses;
    }

    public EmployeeAddress addEmployeeAddress(EmployeeAddress employeeAddress) {
        getEmployeeAddresses().add(employeeAddress);
        employeeAddress.setEmployee(this);

        return employeeAddress;
    }

    public EmployeeAddress removeEmployeeAddress(EmployeeAddress employeeAddress) {
        getEmployeeAddresses().remove(employeeAddress);
        employeeAddress.setEmployee(null);

        return employeeAddress;
    }
```

**EmployeeAddress**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee_address")
@NamedQuery(name="EmployeeAddress.findAll", query="SELECT e FROM EmployeeAddress e")
public class EmployeeAddress implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String apt_no;

    private String city;

    private String country;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="create_dt")
    private Date createDt;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="end_dt")
    private Date endDt;

    private String state;

    private String street_addr;

    private String zip_Code;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Employee
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="emp_id")
    private Employee employee;

    public EmployeeAddress() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getApt_no() {
        return this.apt_no;
    }

    public void setApt_no(String apt_no) {
        this.apt_no = apt_no;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return this.city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return this.country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public Date getCreateDt() {
        return this.createDt;
    }

    public void setCreateDt(Date createDt) {
        this.createDt = createDt;
    }


    public Date getEndDt() {
        return this.endDt;
    }

    public void setEndDt(Date endDt) {
        this.endDt = endDt;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return this.state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getStreet_addr() {
        return this.street_addr;
    }

    public void setStreet_addr(String street_addr) {
        this.street_addr = street_addr;
    }

    public String getZip_Code() {
        return this.zip_Code;
    }

    public void setZip_Code(String zip_Code) {
        this.zip_Code = zip_Code;
    }

    public Employee getEmployee() {
        return this.employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }
```

Now, how do I'm passing this as a Object to my JSP to collect employee information.

How can I display address attributes..

For example:- I display the firstname as below and it works fine but how do I display address.street, address.zip etc??

```
<form:form method="post" action="addemployee" commandName="employee">
        <table class="TFtable">
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="firstname"><spring:message code="label.firstname"/></form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="firstname" /></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: First, your employee may have multiple addresses. So what exactly address do you want to disaply? In any way, you can pass the instance of an entity to the model directly and use it all you want. What's a problem?

Comment: I will have only 2 address..want to understand how to refer 1st ocurrence and second occurence..For ex:--dob I refer directly ie;path=dob..How can I refer address in my path....street_addr[0] ?...